# Как передать данные из метода в модель?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть такой метод:

```
public List<string> GetAccountsYield()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("PddToken", token);
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string result = client.DownloadString(getMail);
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(result);

    var accounts = from account in json["accounts"] select account["fname"].Value<string>();

    return accounts.ToList();
}
```

Порлучаю списком фамилии, нол хочу его структурировать и передать получаемые данные в такую модель к примеру

```
public class Mail
{
    public string Fname { get; set; } 
}
```

И затем выводить уже в View.

Comment: в чем проблема? создавайте в селекте объект нужного класса  и все

Comment: А можно пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструктор можно вызвать непосредственно в селекте

```
var accounts = from account in json["accounts"] 
               select new Mail(){
                   Fname = account["fname"].Value<string>()
               };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = new List<Mail>();

foreach(var account in accounts)
{
    list.Add(new Mail()
    {
        Fname = account;
    });
}
```

Comment: лучше сразу в селекте, который в вопросе уже есть

Comment: Если человек спрашивает подобные вопрос - значит ему нужно отвечать максимально понятно ИМХО. А так вообще бОльшую часть этой конструкции можно заменить лаконичной LINQ-лямбдой.

Comment: так он уже использует лямбду, достаточно просто в селекте конструктор вызвать. А так без пояснений он и будет лепить по три foreach

Comment: @Grundy не лямбду а LINQ если на то пошло. Код в короткой запиcи != понятный код, тем более для новичка, я думаю что это не надо аргументировать!

Comment: собственно ваш код не сильно помогает, и нет никакой разницы ваш код без пояснений, либо код из вопроса

Comment: @Grundy это дополнение к коду, а не готовое решение.

Comment: на данный момент это кусок кода который некуда пришить, причем без пояснений

Comment: @Grundy это ваше мнение, оставайтесь с ним. Человек, задававший вопрос поймёт что с ним делать.